# Breaking an org-mode headline into two

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to break the following headline into two headlines, where `‸` is my text cursor:

```
* An item‸Another item
```

I can hit `M-RET` or `C-RET`, but that will just produce

```
* An item Another item
* ‸
```

To end up with the following, what shortcut can I use?

```
* An item
*‸Another item
```

Edit: `RET C-RET` produces

```
* An item
  Another item
* ‸
```

Comment: How about just hitting the return key and typing an asterisk, and maybe hitting the space bar one time thereafter?  No need for fancy keyboard shortcuts ...

Comment: @lawlist this becomes inconvenient when I'm a few levels deep. I'm using org-superstar-mode, so I never quite know how many asterisks I need to type before hitting the space bar. (Alternatively, I could do asterisk-space and then indent until I'm at the previous level, which is just as annoying.)

Comment: How about `RET C-RET`?

Comment: @NickD I've added your suggestion to the post; it also doesn't quite produce what I'm looking for unfortunately

Comment: It does not do that in my experiments, so there is probably a setting of some option that accounts for the difference. I have no time to play with it ATM, but I'll try some more experiments later on tonight.

Comment: Sorry, my fault: I meant 'RET M-RET`.

Comment: @NickD that's interesting. `RET M-RET` does the same thing as `RET C-RET` for me. If there's a configuration option somewhere I'd like to know what it is ...

Comment: Try setting `org-insert-heading-respect-content` to nil. Then press `M-RET` (`org-meta-return`) and see if it works.

Comment: What @jagrg said (which should be made into an answer...)

Comment: @jagrg This does solve the problem for me, thank you. Please do make it into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Should we change line to headline in the title? WDYT @NickD?

Comment: Good idea: done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `org-insert-heading-respect-content` to nil. Then press `M-RET` (`org-meta-return`).